# python question regarding generator and keyword yield

Tags: python, data-structures, lambda, generator, yield

I am new to Python, so please kindly bear with me. The snippet is from the book "Python cookbook", regarding how to remove dups from a non-hashable collection.

```
def dedup(items, key=None):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        val = item if key is None else key(item)
        if val not in seen:
            yield val
            seen.add(val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [{'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':2, 'y':4}]
    print(list(dedup(a, key=lambda d:(d['x'],d['y']))))
```

when testing, depending on how the "key" is defined, results are shown as:

```
a = [ {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':2, 'y':4}]
>>> list(dedupe(a, key=lambda d: (d['x'],d['y'])))
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 3}, {'x': 2, 'y': 4}]
>>> list(dedupe(a, key=lambda d: d['x']))
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 2, 'y': 4}]
```

now the questions:

1. In the function **dedup**, it seems that the filtered result is saved in set, how does the order of the list is maintained when the item traveled from list to set?
2. no explicit return statement is used in the function, does it mean the set "**seen**" is implicitly returned?
3. Can you explain the two lambda definitions in the tests? From the results, it looks like the first checked both the k and v of the dict type, while the latter only checks on dict's key for duplication.

Comment: The set `seen` is not returned, and has no effect on the order that things are returned in; it's used purely internally to check for the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not physically converting the list into a `set`, notice that the `set` is only used to track seen items. Otherwise, you are just iterating linearly, maintaining the original order
2. No, `seen` is never returned. I'd look into generators, but the gist is that `yield` converts the function into a generator that will produce values for you one at a time. `list` consumes the generator. `seen` will stay in the scope of the function until the generator is completely consumed (the for loop exits)

```py
def f():
    seen = set()
    for i in range(3):
        seen.add(i)
        print(seen)
        yield i

list(f())
{0}
{0, 1}
{0, 1, 2}
[0, 1, 2]
```

3. In the first example, you are filtering on pairs of items, and you don't care about the keys, just the values, so store them in a tuple:

```py
a = set()
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
a.add((d['y'], d['y']))
```

In the second example, you just care about the `x` value, so you can just add that explicitly by calling `seen.add(d['x'])`.

You can test-drive your lambda functions in a `map` to see what they produce:

```py
a = [{'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':3}, {'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':2, 'y':4}]

# first
list(map(lambda d: (d['x'], d['y']), a))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4)]

# second
list(map(lambda d: d['x'], a))
[1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Or in a `for` loop:

```py
# this is bad practice, but it illustrates the point
x = lambda d: d['x']
for val in a:
    print(x(val))
1
1
1
2
```